# Howto initialize repository from ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to initialize a spring repository from org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext?

I tried `(UsersRepository)context.getBean("UsersRepository");` However `UsersRepository` is not a Bean, it is a repository.

I tried `getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(usersRepository);` but does not work without constructing the class, However the repository can not be constructed.

I  tried to declare `@Transactional` and `@Autowired` but this also does not work. the repository object is null.

I have the main object called `core` and into `core` have a `usersession` class and into `usersession` class have a function to verify the user into database, from controller pass the context to core and the core to usersession. I prevent pass the repository to from controller to core, other controllers dont use user session.

Comment: There's not enough info here. Did you add the @Repository annotation? Where is the package you put the repository in relative to the class annotated with the Springbootapplication annotation? Maybe the repository or the service isn't getting componentscanned. Wire the spring beans, don't use getbean on the appcontext and don't pass the app context around

Comment: @Repository does not exists in spring boot. The repository is started as bean, the `UsersRepository` is defined in `context.getBeanDefinitionNames()` but I do not know how to initialize it.

Comment: @NathanHughes Using `@Repository` is almost ever necessary.

Comment: OP: A repository is *one sort of bean*, but you shouldn't be manually autowiring anything when using Spring. Post actual code, but generally whatever you're trying to autowire *into* should be an `@Component` or constructed in an `@Bean` method.

Comment: Add @Component over `core` and `usersession` but the @Autowired does not work.

Comment: Works fine adding the autowired to core in controller instead of construct as java object. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that how you have organized your code in packages has resulted in componentscan missing some things, read this:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html